# How to sort posts by topic from people I follow on Pinterest

Tags: sorting, pinterest

I want to be able to sort the pins from people I follow by topic. So I want to be able to see only Food posts from people I follow (or Fashion or whatever), not from everyone. Is there any way to do this?